# Coin3D Crop the current View

Tags: c++, coin3d

In coin 3D, I have a scene setup, and the user can view the scene from various directions using a X,Y and Z  and this will move the camera.

when these buttons are selected, I would like the viewer to Basically crop the output and the camera needs to zoom is as close as possible so that I can see the rendering in full at the current angle of viewing.

I have tried various things, including setting up the Camera->heightangle

Setting up Camera->Viewall, but the viewall will make sure the whole scene is visible in all 3 dimensions.

I need a better solution.

please assit.

Comment: So basically, I want to apply a 2D bounding box over a 3D view. once I have that 2D bounding box, I can work some magic, but im not sure how to do it.

Comment: The feature is called `boxZoom` in OpenInventor and FreeCAD (using Coin3D). See [here](http://free-cad.sourceforge.net/SrcDocu/d2/d2f/NavigationStyle_8cpp_source.html) for the implementation.